# iPad app - touchesBegan double tapping not correct

Tags: ipad, touchesbegan

I have a UIViewController that has a touchesBegan function and outputs the positions.

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 
    NSLog(@"in");

    NSArray *touchesArray = [touches allObjects];
    for(int i=0; i<1; i++)
    {
        UITouch *touch = (UITouch *)[touchesArray objectAtIndex:i];
        CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
        NSLog(@"point = %f %f",point.x,point.y);
    }
}
```

If I double tap quickly towards the middle of the screen, I get the following output

```
2012-02-12 21:47:13.522 MoreMost[479:707] in
2012-02-12 21:47:13.523 MoreMost[479:707] point = 698.000000 86.000000
2012-02-12 21:47:13.617 MoreMost[479:707] in
2012-02-12 21:47:13.619 MoreMost[479:707] point = 39.000000 22.000000
```

why is that second tap being registered as (39,22)...which is like the top left corner of the iPad. However, I was tapping in the middle.

So, I'd like to solve this in two ways:

```
1) somehow, not let the user double tap (however it seems even when I double tap fast, the touchesBegan function is called on two separate occassions)
2) figure out why that 2nd tap is being registered with the wrong coordinates.
```

Comment: 1)When you tap twice `touchesBegan:withEvent:` will be called twice. (That is how it works) 2)I suspect that each tap of your double tap is falling in two separate views, don't ask me how I don't know. But the most reasonable solution would be to index your locations to a known view, like:`locationInView:self.view` instead of `touch.view` which would be any view for which the touch passes a hit test.

Comment: yes, that worked. not sure why I put touch.view, lol. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should be  CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];...not "touch.view"